# Where Do You Set the Top OS Bar Backcolor

Tags: maui

I'm trying to figure out where you set the backcolor that's used on the top OS info bar on devices in a MAUI app.  Here's a picture of the section I mean, with a red circle around the part I want to change:

[image]

Comment: As Gerald pointed, it seems that has not been ported to the .NET MAUI Community Toolkit,for more details, you could refer to [this thread](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/issues/85).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something that still needs a platform-specific approach at this time. Go into the `Platforms\Android\Resources\values` folder and find the `colors.xml` file.

[image: Screenshot of the Visual Studio Solution Explorer showing the colors.xml file]

Inside of that file, for a default template, you should find three values: colorPrimary, colorPrimaryDark and colorAccent.

colorPrimaryDark is the one that influences the color of your statusbar.

We have an Effect to do this in the [Xamarin Community Toolkit](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/tree/main/src/CommunityToolkit/Xamarin.CommunityToolkit/Effects/StatusBar). Unfortunately it seems that has not been ported to the .NET MAUI Community Toolkit at the time of writing.